# Generating a list of URLs in Python based on a .csv list of queries

Tags: python, url, csv, dictionary

I've got a .csv with 10,000+ rows of queries that I'd like to add on to the end of a domain (www.abcdef.com/xxxxxx).

What is the best way to go about building all of these URLs?

I'm a python beginner and I know how to generate a list based off using a manually created dictionary, but how do I read/write from a .csv row by row?

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Here's your clue: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 1):

For reading and writing CSV see [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module.
For manipulating URLs, see [urlparse.urljoin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin) (in Python3 `urlllib.parse` module)

I would also recommend to use `set()` for storing URL for each domain. You avoid duplicates this way.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) that can do this work for you.